# How do I get MySQL table entities in excel

Tags: php, mysql

What I have done is get the data from MySQL to excel in csv format but I am not getting the entities of that table like if I have a table member having these 3 entities

memberid membername memberemail

I am getting the data of these entities like

```
1 alishah test@test.com
```

What I want is when I download an excel it gets header with it like

```
memberid membername memberemail
1        alishah    test@test.com
```

What I did for excel is

```
<?php
    $selectUserData = "SELECT * FROM tbl_member";
    $export = $conn->query($selectUserData);
    $fp= fopen('php://output', 'w');
    foreach ($export as $fields) 
    {
        fputcsv($fp, $fields);
    }
    header("Content-Type: text/csv;charset=utf-8" );
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=member.csv");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply write a line with the column headers before writing the data to the csv.

```
<?php
    $selectUserData = "SELECT * FROM tbl_member";
    $export = $conn->query($selectUserData);
    $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    fwrite($fp,'"memberid","membername","memberemail"'."\n");
    foreach ($export as $fields) 
    {
        fputcsv($fp, $fields);
    }
    header("Content-Type: text/csv;charset=utf-8" );
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=member.csv");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");
?>
```

Comment: Is this a good way to add column header manually? What if I add another column? I have to change the backend also, right?

Comment: In this case, yes you would have to change the code. Of course, you could read the column names and output them before the data rows.